# Getting this is not a function error in Angular Jasmine testing

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to testing in Angular, and just trying to get my first test to pass.I am looking to resolve this error. I am not sure what to do next. some help would be amazing!!

Here is my component.ts file:
[component.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJCwm.png)

HEre is my component.spec.ts file:
[component.spec.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn33w.png)

And here is my error message:
[jasmine error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwUlG.png)

I kind of know the problem just dont really know the approach to resolve this format date error.
I really just want to get the first test passing.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

You should mock your dependencies, in this case:

```
...
const sharedServiceMock = {
    formatDate: jest.fn();
} as unknown as SharedService; // Just if you need to type it. Don't use any

beforeEach(async () => {
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: SharedService, useValue: sharedServiceMock },
        ...
    ]
    ...
}).compileComponents();
...
```

Unit testing means, you mock everything external and just test the results of your components functions. It doesn't matter, if the implementation of "SharedService" works as expected, because you should allready have a unittest in the shared.service.spec.ts.

If the formatDate function should returning something, what gets used in a component function (e.g. in a condition), then you can mock a return value (just an example):

```
describe('component function', () => {
    it('should run successful', {
        sharedServiceMock.formatDate.mockReturnValue('1970-01-01');
        expect(testUnit.someFunction()).toBe(...);
    }) 
})
```